# Background music running in iPhone application interrupt phone calls

Tags: iphone, ios4, xcode4.2

I am developing an iPhone application with Music running. In my application downloading a music file with web service and running this music in background and foreground,this is working perfectly.

But the background music running affect the phone call, alarm etc. How to overcome this issue? How to automatically resume the music after phone call, alarm, etc?

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911758/how-to-resume-background-music-after-out-going-phone-call-ios

Comment: In my application music resume after phone call  when app in foreground .But don't work the same in background.